# I want to print some posters but don't know where to look for Images which are not Copyrighted?

Tags: images, copyright, free

I started a new website for selling posters of Movies, Celebrities and Sports. Problem is most of the images that I got from Internet are now claimed by some people that they have copyrights of the images. I am trying to find the right Images but its very difficult for me. I looked in many free stock images website but was unable to get Images which are worth printing.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>I am not a lawyer. You should get one, if you are concerned about possible legal issues.</sub>

---

First of all, pictures that are not copyrighted (i. e. in public domain) are not your only hope. There are quite a lot pictures that once you get them might be legally used for any purpose (incl. for profit), modified and/or reproduced without royalty, they are called [‘free’](https://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.html) (as in ‘freedom’) or ‘libre’ ones. The popular copyright licenses for free/libre works of art are: [CC0](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/zero/1.0/legalcode), [CC-BY](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by/4.0/legalcode), [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/legalcode), [Free Art License](http://artlibre.org/licence/lal/en/). (Do not forget to understand them, they have certain requirements.)

You might use, for example, [Google Advanced Image Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_image_search?hl=en) (usage rights: ‘free to use, share or modify, even commercially’) to find free/libre images on some topic, but you have to be careful: copyright status might be mislabeled, you’d better double-check it with reverse image search and common sense. Some resources (like [Wikimedia Commons](https://commons.wikimedia.org/)) are quite trustworthy, some are not.

Also, a copyright of author of an image is not the only thing you have to be aware of: if it’s a photography of a person, that person also have certain right that varies with jurisdiction which you might violate; some words or (a name of a sport event for example) might be trademarks, et cetera, et cetera.